# how to add zero before a number if the number is less than 10 in a dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe

I had a column in data frame and I wanted to convert each value in the column cpro to a two digit number by adding '0' in front of it if the number is less than 10.
I had done it  in the following way '0'.join(df.loc[df['cpro']<10,'cpro'].astype(str).tolist())

Answer (score 1):

Where `x` is the string to pad:

```
x.zfill(2)
```

Comment: is x an element in the df['cpro']

Comment: if `df['cpro']` is a string, otherwise use `str(df['cpro'])`.

Comment: but still i am not getting the required answer

Comment: i had done for x in str(sensus['cpro']):
     x.zfill(2)